# empty row for datagrid in wpf vb.net

Tags: wpf, vb.net, datagrid

at first sorry for bad english!
I'm working with vb.net and i want to use a datagrid in my app
I want to use some text from code and insert a row to datagrid , i searched for it and find this post.
I'm use code from this post :
[click for that post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32893206/wpf-avoid-adding-a-duplicate-row)

a row will add by this code but its empty !
tnx !
here is vb.net codes :

```
Private Sub Window_Loaded(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)
    Dim row As String() = New String() {"aaa", "150", "2000", "10520"}
    Dim dmb As New MyProduct
    dmb.ItemNumber = "abc001"
    dmb.ItemDescription = "bla bla bla"
    dmb.ItemQty = 1
    dmb.ItemUnitPrice = 123.45
    grd.Items.Add(dmb)
    timer1.Enabled = True
End Sub
Public Class MyProduct
    Public Property ItemNumber As String
    Public Property ItemDescription As String
    Public Property ItemUnitPrice As Double
    Public Property ItemQty As Integer
End Class
```

here is xaml code:

```
            <DataGrid x:Name="grd">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Width="100" Header="name" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Width="100" Header="desc" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Width="100" Header="unt"  />
                <DataGridTextColumn Width="100" Header="qty"  />
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
```

Comment: I don't really know where you are stuck. [Take a look here](https://wpf-tutorial.com/datagrid-control/introduction/) and you may have a more clear view on how the `DataGrid` works.

Comment: @P.Manthe I used same code but the row to be added is empty !

Comment: Did you defined the `DataGrid.Columns` and `DataGridTextColumn`?. I used the same code and the row is not empty. So I suggest that you update your question and show *your* code.

Comment: @P.Manthe I added the code. tnx for helping !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you didn't define the `Column`properly. You need to bind it to some property. Otherwise there is no way for the `DataGrid` to "guess" what to show.
Try this code for the `DataGrid.Columns` definition:

```
<DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="name" Binding="{Binding ItemNumber}"/>
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="desc" Binding="{Binding ItemDescription}"/>
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="qty" Binding="{Binding ItemQty}"/>
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="unt" Binding="{Binding ItemUnitPrice}"/>
</DataGrid.Columns>
```

You can take a look there: [DataGrid tutorial](https://wpf-tutorial.com/datagrid-control/introduction/) for more explanations on how to use the `DataGrid`